# Stack Overflow Error when using memcpy to copy 1d array to 2d array

Tags: arrays, mfc, stack-overflow, memcpy

In one of the button clicked function of my MFC project, I got the following code which try to copy an array of data to another array:

```
Char dest[2500][50];
double totalNum = CountNum*2;
for (int n=0; n< totalNum; n++){
    memcpy(dest[n], readingdata+n*14, 13);
    dest[n][13]=0;
}
```

If I run this code once or twice, there is nothing wrong. But when I try to run this code several time more, the program gives me a exception error: `Stack Overflow`. And the error occurs in `chkstk.asm` file, it is in line 99:

```
test dword ptr [eax],eax ; probe page
```

Can Anyone help me out and explain how does this cause the stack overflow problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use dynamic array here

```
double totalNum = CountNum*2;    
ViChar (*dest)[50] = new ViChar[totalNum][50];
for (int n=0; n< totalNum; n++){
    memcpy(dest[n], readingdata+n*14, 13);
    dest[n][13]=0;
}

delete [] dest;
```